# Testing for infinity in CUDA

Tags: c++, c, cuda, numerical

In a CUDA program, I recently switched from testing for inifinity using

```
return x==INFINITY || x==-INFINITY;
```

where `INFINITY` is from math.h, to

```
return !isfinite(x);
```

and was quite surprised to get different results. [gnu.org](http://www.gnu.org/s/libc/manual/html_node/Infinity-and-NaN.html) suggests that they actually should behave similarly. Am I missing something? Is it not allowed to use `INFINITY` in a CUDA kernel?

**Edit:**
I just discovered `isinf` and noticed that checking using

```
return isinf(x);
```

gives the same result as the INFINITY check. Why isn't 
`isfinite(x)==!isinf(x)`?

Comment: For what values did the results differ?  What were the results?  What were the expected results?

Comment: i'm not sure yet, but it seems isfinite is more strict than the INFINITY test.

Comment: @stephen canon: granted, but the Cg docs don't mention the INFINITY macro from math.h, the difference to which I am asking about. Apparently the INFINITY macro does work like isinf (see my edit), so it has some relevance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`isfinite(a)` is the same as `!isnan(a) && !isinf(a)`.  If `x` is NaN, then both `isfinite(x)` and `isinf(x)` are false.

Comment: My check for NaN `(x!=x)` passes, so according to this test there are no NaNs. However, if Crashworks is right, then this might actually be the solution.

Comment: @hannes: what GPU and version of CUDA are you using?

Comment: @hannes: Make sure `(x!=x)` isn't being optimized away by your compiler.

Comment: @Billy ONeal: the nan-test works correctly when inject NaNs manually.

Answer (score 3):

`isinf()` checks only for `+INFINITY` or `-INFINITY`.

`!isfinite()` checks for `+INFINITY`, `-INFINITY` or `NaN`.

Answer (score 1):

Floating-point comparisons aren't necessarily valid. For example, it's possible that `(1.0f + 3.0f != 2.0f + 2.0f)`.It's perfectly possible that isfinite considers values less than a specific constant apart to be equal to INFINITE or -INFINITE, whereas you wrote a literal equality.

Comment: It is **not** possible that `1.0f + 3.0f != 2.0f + 2.0f` on any system with the IEEE-754 arithmetic (or even on systems that aren't-quite-IEEE-754-compliant like some GPUs).  Floating-point is not black magic.  There are well-defined rules for when it rounds and when it does not.

Answer (score 1):

Many GPUs and SIMD units are not totally IEEE754 compliant, especially for edge cases around infinities and NaNs. Just last night I noticed that a particular vector processor I worked with claimed that ∞+1 ≠ ∞ , and x == x even for x ∈ NaN.

Answer (score 0):

In the recent post [Checking if a matrix contains nans or infinite values in CUDA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22734067/checking-if-a-matrix-contains-nans-or-infinite-values-in-cuda/23461764#23461764), Robert Crovella has suggested using `isinf()` to check for infinite values in CUDA.

Below I'm providing an example of checking for infinite values in an array using `isinf()` and by exploiting CUDA Thrust. Perhaps it could be useful as reference for other users. The example below is equivalent to Matlab's `d_result=isinf(d_data);`. It is different from the example I posted for the question quoted above in that the present one checks for each individual element is infinite while the other one checked if the whole array contained at least one `NaN` and was equivalent to Matlab's `sum(isnan(d_data));`.

```
#include <thrust/sequence.h>

#include <thrust/device_vector.h>
#include <thrust/host_vector.h>
#include <thrust\device_vector.h>
#include <thrust\reduce.h>

#include <float.h>

// --- Operator for testing inf values
struct isinf_test { 
    __host__ __device__ bool operator()(const float a) const {
        return isinf(a);
    }
};

void main(){

    const int N = 10;

    thrust::host_vector<float> h_data(N);
    for (int i=0; i<N; i++)
        h_data[i] = rand()/RAND_MAX;

    h_data[0] = FLT_MAX/FLT_MIN;

    thrust::device_vector<float> d_data(h_data);
    thrust::device_vector<float> d_result(h_data);

    thrust::transform(d_data.begin(), d_data.end(), d_result.begin(), isinf_test());

    for (int i=0; i<N; i++) {
        float val = d_result[i];
        printf("Isinf test for element number %i equal to %f\n",i,val);
    }

    getchar();

}
```