# Checking if a matrix contains nans or infinite values in CUDA

Tags: c++, cuda, nan, thrust

What is an efficient way to check a large matrix for `inf`/`nan` elements in CUDA (C++)? The matrix is stored as `float*` in the GPU memory. I don't need the location of those elements, just a boolean yes/no answer if at least one bad entry is present.

The options are:

- have one kernel check the whole array (easy to implement but probably slow)
- have multiple kernels check e.g. the rows and combine the output with OR (are there any CUDA builtins for doing this efficiently?)
- ..other ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Letting one kernel check one row seems a reasonable compromise between effiicency and ease of implementation to me. But I do OpenCL, which isn't quite the same as CUDA.

Comment: You're likely to get better results if you check the values as you generate them, which I imagine is already split between cores anyway.

Answer (score 6):

There are instrinsics for this, but the functions available for C99 should be fine:

```
isnan()
```

To test for inf, you can use:

```
isinf()
```

It's rarely faster to have multiple kernels do the same work of a single well written kernel, so I'm not sure why you think having a single kernel would be slow.  This algorithm is likely to be memory-bound, so you want to focus on read data access efficiency, i.e. coalescing.  In CUDA, the easy way to go through a matrix is to have each thread handle a column.  This can be implemented efficiently with a for-loop and results in perfectly coalesced reads.

Since you only care about a single result with no indices, we can have multiple threads writing to a (boolean) result *without* atomics, for further efficiency, since any threads that might be writing to the result would all be writing the same value.

Another optimization strategy one might consider would be an early-exit strategy, but this does not optimize the worst-case timing, but in fact makes it longer, so I would dispense with that unless average throughput is a big issue.

Here's a complete worked example (using test for nan as an example):

```
$ cat t383.cu
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define DSIZEW 10000
#define DSIZEH 2000
#define nTPB 256
#define BLKS 16

__global__ void isnan_test(float *data, int width, int height, bool *result){

  int idx = threadIdx.x+blockDim.x*blockIdx.x;

  while (idx < width){
    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
      if (isnan(data[(i*width) + idx])) *result = false;
    idx += gridDim.x+blockDim.x;
    }
}

int main(){

  float *d_data, *h_data;
  bool  *d_result, h_result=true;
  const char type = '0';

  cudaMalloc((void **)&d_data, sizeof(float)*DSIZEW*DSIZEH);
  cudaMalloc((void **)&d_result, sizeof (bool));
  h_data=(float *)malloc(sizeof(float)*DSIZEW*DSIZEH);
  for (int i=0; i<DSIZEH*DSIZEW; i++)
    h_data[i] = rand()/RAND_MAX;
  cudaMemcpy(d_data, h_data, sizeof(float)*DSIZEW*DSIZEH, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
  cudaMemcpy(d_result, &h_result, sizeof(bool), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
  isnan_test<<<BLKS,nTPB>>>(d_data, DSIZEW, DSIZEH, d_result);
  cudaMemcpy(&h_result, d_result, sizeof(bool), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
  if (!h_result) {printf("error in no-NAN check\n"); return 1;}
  float my_nan = nanf(&type); // create a NAN value
  cudaMemcpy(d_data, &my_nan, sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
  isnan_test<<<BLKS,nTPB>>>(d_data, DSIZEW, DSIZEH, d_result);
  cudaMemcpy(&h_result, d_result, sizeof(bool), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
  if (h_result) {printf("error in NAN check\n"); return 1;}
  printf("Success\n");
  return 0;
}


$ nvcc -arch=sm_20 -o t383 t383.cu
$ ./t383
Success
$
```

Note that I have dispensed with [proper cuda error checking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14038589/what-is-the-canonical-way-to-check-for-errors-using-the-cuda-runtime-api) for clarity/brevity, but that is always recommended.

For further optimization, you can play with the blocks per grid parameter (`BLKS`) and the threads per block parameter (`nTPB`), however, to some degree the optimal values of these will depend on which GPU you are running on.

Comment: The type-generic functions `isinf()` and `isnan()`, as specified by the C99 and C++ standards, should work fine in device code, I don't think there is a need to drop down to the underlying type-specific device intrinsics.

Answer (score 3):

Your problem can be recast as a **reduction operation**. This can be effectively implemented by using **CUDA Thrust**. You can transform the original array to a boolean array by using CUDA's  `isnan` or `isinf` and then reducing the transformed array. All that can be performed by expoiting **`thrust::transform_reduce`**.

Below is an example, constructed around the one that Robert Crovella has already presented to you. The code below implements in CUDA the equivalent of **Matlab's `sum(isnan(array))`**.

```
#include <thrust\device_vector.h>
#include <thrust\reduce.h>

#define DSIZEW 10000
#define DSIZEH 2000

// --- Operator for testing nan values
struct isnan_test { 
    __host__ __device__ bool operator()(const float a) const {
        return isnan(a);
    }
};

void main(){

    thrust::host_vector<float> h_data(DSIZEW*DSIZEH);
    for (int i=0; i<DSIZEH*DSIZEW; i++)
        h_data[i] = rand()/RAND_MAX;

    const char type = '0';
    float my_nan = nanf(&type); // create a NAN value
    h_data[0] = my_nan;

    thrust::device_vector<float> d_data(h_data);

    bool h_result = thrust::transform_reduce(d_data.begin(), d_data.end(), isnan_test(), 0, thrust::plus<bool>());
    printf("Result = %d\n",h_result);

    getchar();

}
```